# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Tags: opencv

I am currently using Mac OS10.12
when I run the following snippet of code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('happyfish.jpeg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get an error saying:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'

My OpenCV is installed fine. When I run the imread command it does execute.

Comment: Please post the full error statement. It might have more information in it. It seems like your opencv libs have been copied to usr/local. Have you tried using super user ?

Comment: no i have not used super user 
the error is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Comment: when i run it on anaconda it gives me this :

Traceback (most recent call last):

' File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
 File "/Users/Apple/Documents/anisha/project/test/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow''

Comment: try running this file with sudo. If it works, it means that your opencv libs need to be copied to /usr/include.